# Spring Security not performing any role/authorization check for the API requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I wrote the below spring security filter which works as expected for most part but it doesn't check for any roles/authorizations that user might or might not have:

```
    http
            .anonymous()
            .disable()
            .requestMatcher(request -> {
                return request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("api-docs");
            }).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("DEVELOPER").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(this.authExceptionFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
```

In the above snipet, I have added .hasAnyRole("DEVELOPER") to allow the user access to this API only if it has the DEVELOPER role. The user was authenticated but it did not have any DEVELOPER role attached to it but he was not denied access to the API.

Comment: can you post `authEntryPoint()` and `authExceptionFilter()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("DEVELOPER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(this.authExceptionFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
```